# How to add flash to ios app?

Tags: ios, flash, uiwebview

Here is the thing, I am developing an app playing video using MPMoviePlayerController. When the user pauses the video, I show them an image( a button, when the user clicks the button, a UIWebview will be loaded) with advertisement on it, just like this:

[image]

Now instead of showing users picture advertisement, I want to show them advertisements that moves, like a flash file. Like the home page of Google.
I am a newbie to IOS development, anybody has suggestion about how to do this? Thx.

Comment: Apple doesnt support flash as far as i know... but your app might not pass the review process if you are trying to display your own ads. you have to use one of apple ad systems, or admob.

Answer (score 0):

I found some cheap and quick way, LOL. I turned the flash to html by [swf decompiler](http://www.swf-decompiler.org/) and then add the html to my app instead.